# jQuery sortables - nested helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

**I have two jQuery scripts on jsFiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/9uhfX/14/
- http://jsfiddle.net/9uhfX/15/

**First one**

The first one is how I want it to look. Nesting list elements with nesting sorting functions. This one does not work with puting the list elements inside other list elements.

**Second one**

The second one contains a min-height and here it works with puting list elements inside other list elements.

**The question**

Is it possible to add the dropzone (helper?) inside the list element instead of out in the ul, to make it not look like the second example. Define an own drop area?

I might want all dropable areas visible from start.

Anything that might make this drag drop easier and more beautiful are welome.

Answer (score 0):

There is a already a own drop-area, the empty ul-elements. To make it look "better" use a different background for ul(for example "inherit"):

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/9uhfX/18/